# Slurm job array submission severely underutilizing available resources

Tags: arrays, multithreading, mpi, cluster-computing, slurm

The SLURM job array submission isn't working as I expected. When I run my sbatch script to create the array and run the programs I expect it to fully utilize all the cores that are available, however, it only allows one job from the array to run on the a given node at a time. SCONTROL shows the job using all 36 cores on the node when I specified 4 cores for the process. Additionally, I want to restrict the jobs to running on one specific node, however if other nodes are unused, it will submit a job onto them as well, using every core available on that node.

I've tried submitting the jobs by changing the parameters for --nodes, --ntasks, --nodelist, --ntasks-per-node, --cpus-per-task, setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, and specifying the number of cores for `mpirun` directly.  None of these options seemed to change anything at all.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --time=2:00:00   # walltime
#SBATCH --ntasks=1   # number of processor cores (i.e. tasks)
#SBATCH --nodes=1    # number of nodes
#SBATCH --nodelist node001
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=9
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=500MB   # memory per CPU core

#SBATCH --array=0-23%8

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK

mpirun -n 4 MYPROGRAM
```

I expected to be able to run eight instances of `MYPROGRAM`, each utilizing four cores for a parallel operation. In total, I expected to use 32 cores at a time for `MYPROGRAM`, plus however many cores are needed to run the job submission program.

Instead, my `squeue` output looks like this

```
JOBID          PARTITION    NAME      USER   ST   TIME  NODES CPUS
  num_[1-23%6]  any      MYPROGRAM   user   PD   0:00      1 4
  num_0         any      MYPROGRAM   user    R   0:14      1 36
```

It says that I am using all available cores on the node for this process, and will not allow additional array jobs to begin. While `MYPROGRAM` runs exactly as expected, there is only once instance of it running at any given time.

And my `SCONTROL` output looks like this:

```
   UserId=user(225589) GroupId=domain users(200513) MCS_label=N/A
   Priority=4294900562 Nice=0 Account=(null) QOS=normal
   JobState=PENDING Reason=Resources Dependency=(null)
   Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
   RunTime=00:00:00 TimeLimit=02:00:00 TimeMin=N/A
   SubmitTime=2019-06-21T18:46:25 EligibleTime=2019-06-21T18:46:26
   StartTime=Unknown EndTime=Unknown Deadline=N/A
   PreemptTime=None SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0
   LastSchedEval=2019-06-21T18:46:28
   Partition=any AllocNode:Sid=w***:45277
   ReqNodeList=node001 ExcNodeList=(null)
   NodeList=(null) SchedNodeList=node001
   NumNodes=1-1 NumCPUs=4 NumTasks=1 CPUs/Task=4 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
   TRES=cpu=4,mem=2000M,node=1
   Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=9:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
   MinCPUsNode=36 MinMemoryCPU=500M MinTmpDiskNode=0
   Features=(null) DelayBoot=00:00:00
   Gres=(null) Reservation=(null)
   OverSubscribe=NO Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)

   Power=

JobId=1694 ArrayJobId=1693 ArrayTaskId=0 JobName=launch_vasp.sh
   UserId=user(225589) GroupId=domain users(200513) MCS_label=N/A
   Priority=4294900562 Nice=0 Account=(null) QOS=normal
   JobState=RUNNING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
   Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=1 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
   RunTime=00:00:10 TimeLimit=02:00:00 TimeMin=N/A
   SubmitTime=2019-06-21T18:46:25 EligibleTime=2019-06-21T18:46:26
   StartTime=2019-06-21T18:46:26 EndTime=2019-06-21T20:46:26 Deadline=N/A
   PreemptTime=None SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0
   LastSchedEval=2019-06-21T18:46:26
   Partition=any AllocNode:Sid=w***:45277
   ReqNodeList=node001 ExcNodeList=(null)
   NodeList=node001
   BatchHost=node001
   NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=36 NumTasks=1 CPUs/Task=4 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
   TRES=cpu=36,mem=18000M,node=1,billing=36
   Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=9:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
   MinCPUsNode=36 MinMemoryCPU=500M MinTmpDiskNode=0
   Features=(null) DelayBoot=00:00:00
   Gres=(null) Reservation=(null)
   OverSubscribe=NO Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)

   Power=
```

Something is going wrong in how SLURM is assigning cores to tasks, but nothing I've tried changes anything. I'd appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: `--ntasks=1` seems to conflict with `--ntasks-per-node=9`. Also, the script running `mpirun -np 4 ...` adds to the confusion (it looks like it should be `1` or `9`). You should also double check in the SLURM config that partitions are not in `Exclusive` mode (e.g. only one job can run on a given node)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the [slurm.conf](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html) file allows consumable resources.  The default is to assign nodes exclusively. I had to add the following lines to allow per-score scheduling

```
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
```